# How to run scrapy spider with celery

Tags: django, scrapy, celery

I'm trying to run a scrapy spider which takes some argument and runing it with os.system. But the celery task(scraper) doesn't gets executed untill it finishes.

**Spider**

```py
class SpecificAuthorQuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """Extracts the quotes from specific author"""

    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    name = "some-quotes"

    def __init__(self, author=None, **kwargs):
        self.author = author
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        item = QuotesItem()

        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')
        for quote in all_div_quotes:
            title = quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first().replace('”', '').replace("“", "")
            author = quote.css('.author::text').extract_first()

            # Check if author's name matches
            if author.strip().lower() == self.author.strip().lower():
                item['text'] = title
                item['author'] = author
                yield item

        # Crawl Next Page
        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

**Task**

```py
@shared_task
def task_scrape_from_author(author_name):
    """Scrape quotes from author"""
    django_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    os.chdir(str(django_path)+"/scraper")
    os.system(
        "scrapy crawl some-quotes -a author='{}'".format(author_name))
```

**View**

```py
def scrape_quotes_from_author(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        author_name = request.POST.get("athr_name")
        task_scrape_from_author.delay(author_name)
        messages.add_message(
            request, messages.INFO, 'Started crawling quotes from {}'.format(author_name))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:index"))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

> [Github Repo](https://github.com/sbhusal123/Django-Admin-Scrapy/)

I don't understand why is the task not getting completed and interrupted without any messages. I tried setting max timeout also but that din't worked.

Comment: I had the same issue I had a project with Django + Scrapy. I solve the problem with Crawler runner.

Comment: Can you please provide some reference.

Comment: We will figure it out. I am using the same system. I answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I make a table for spider_name and spider_class.

model.py

```
class Spiders(models.Model):
    spider_class = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Spider Class",null=True)
    spider_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Spider Name",null=True)
```

I collect all spider_name and class' here.

view.py

```
from .model import Spiders
from spider_dir.start import startallSpiders

def runAllspiders(request):
    all_class = []
    spiders = Spiders.objects.all()
    for spider in spiders:
        spider_name = spider.spider_name
        name = 'spider_dir.spider_dir.spiders.'+spider_name
        i = importlib.import_module(name)
        class_ = getattr(i, spider.spider_class)
        all_class.append(class_)
    try:
        startallSpiders(all_class)
        messages.success(request,"Spiders works fine")
    except:
        messages.warning(request,"An error occure")
    
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

I make a start py in scrapy dir

I use crochet to start all of the spiders at once.

start.py

```
from .spider_dir import settings as st
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from crochet import setup
setup()

def startallSpiders(all_Class):
    for class_ in all_Class:
        crawler_settings = Settings()
        setup()
        crawler_settings.setmodule(st)
        runner= CrawlerRunner(settings=crawler_settings)
        runner.crawl(class_)
```

settings.py You have to append Django settings in scrapy settings.

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('.')))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
import django
django.setup()
```

I figure with Crawlerrunner and everything works fine for 6 months.